# How to apply predefined css class to a html tag in css file

Tags: css

In my HTML code there are multiple `<pre>` tags. In my local CSS file I styled my `<pre>` tag like

```
pre {    
  font: ..    
  ..    
}
```

Is there any way to apply bootstrap class in above code (i.e. in CSS file)     so that I don't need to apply same bootstrap class to all `<pre>` tags?

Comment: just copy paste bootstrap class content in your pre tag css.

Comment: @murli2308  this is fine but is there no other solution to avoid copying same content.

Comment: if you are using `sass` or `less` css pre-processors then you can add class in side class. otherwise using normal css this is not possible to include a class within another class

Comment: I don't think there is a modular bootstrap so you cannot just apply the `<pre>` style without the rest of bootstrap. As @murli2308 said, the quickest way is to copy the properties into your CSS file

Answer (score 0):

Where ever you have a pre tag make it a class so that in the css file when you write pre {... all instances of pre will have that class applied.

Comment: My question is different, i did what you are saying. I want to apply some bootstrap class inside the definition.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you use pre-processors like **SASS** o **LESS**.

If you use for example SASS version of Bootstrap, you can extend `pre` tag in the following way:

```
pre {    
  @extend .your-css-class   
}
```

Where `.your-css-class` is the name of css class that is considered *source* of css rules that you want to apply also to `pre` elements